# The cognito form does not use the whole screen

Tags: cognito-forms, css

I'm using cognitoforms and when i'm creating a new page for the cognito form it does not fill the whole page. It is only uses the half page.

[image]

Here is my style for this form

[image]

and the code that i paste

```
</style>
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/include/required"></script>
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/session/script/f3f962b6-e5f0-4f6a-97df-62fc3da1dbd3"></script>
<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "1" });</script>
</div>
```

Do i need to add css to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Forms in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) are designed to responsively adapt from 300 to 800 pixels, and automatically switch between one and two column layouts.  They are not designed to be larger than 800 pixels wide.  Of course, this is browser pixels, not device pixels, as high-DPI devices scale these automatically.

That being said I cannot tell if the form you took a picture of is actually rendering correctly and is scaled down in the picture or if something else is wrong.  However, as you can see from this CodePen, your form does render correctly when embedded using the code snippet you provided:

http://codepen.io/jamiemthomas/pen/EaBWQZ